# Creating a query linked to a value in a list box

Tags: sql, vba, t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The below retreive query works fine until i insert the WHERE clause which is linked to a list box taking the text value in the field 'Group' from the table 'tblTeams'.

Both the values from the table 'tblTeams' as well as that from the list box (sourcing another table) are values.

Looking at the code, the list box value is correct but for some reason does not link to the table.  I am wondering if there is something wrong with the syntax?

```
SELECT [tblTeams].[Department], [tblTeams].[Team], [tblTeams].[Group] FROM [tblTeams] 
ORDER BY [tblTeams].[Department] 
WHERE [tblTeams].[group]= '" & lstGroup.Value & "'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where clause needs to be before order by clause. [See documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb208930(v=office.12).aspx)

```
SELECT [tblTeams].[Department], [tblTeams].[Team], [tblTeams].[Group] FROM [tblTeams] 
WHERE [tblTeams].[group]= '" & lstGroup.Value & "'"
ORDER BY [tblTeams].[Department]
```

Comment: Its been a while since I have been programming. Thanks a million!